# simulating air friction in gazebo for flying objects

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi guys,
gazebo do not simulate air friction.
So how can i modell this in gazebo?
in order to simulate a quadrotor "relatively"realistic, i need to take air friction into account.
So i thought whether it is possible to model air friction by an "against force" or rather by an "against torque" which are quadratically proportional to the linear velocity and angular velocity.
Are there any plugins or written nodes or anything i can use to achieve this goal??
Any suggestion are welcome.
how can i start generally?
thanks
regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12554/simulating-air-friction-in-gazebo-for-flying-objects/) by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2012-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Colleagues and me are actually looking into that too right now. Currently, I have two possible approaches in mind (not tested yet):

1. Implement a new plugin starting from a copy of the gazebo_ros_force plugin and apply the necessary forces for simulating air friction there. This plugin could also receive the desired wrench generated by the quadrotor control system and apply them. The quadrotor will then exhibit "realistic" behavior out of the box when spawned in gazebo
2. Use the unmodified gazebo_ros_force plugin and do the calculations (mixing of air friction forces and desired wrench from the controller) in an ROS node outside gazebo. This node then publishes the resulting overall wrench to the gazebo_ros_force plugin. This approach gets away without writing a new plugin, but the friction forces would be calculated outside gazebo.

See also this related question: http://answers.ros.org/question/3489/applying-wrench-to-object-and-update-rate-of

I'll try to clean up our basic quadrotor model for gazebo a little and upload it in the next 2 or 3 days. I'm not aware of an existing available implementation of a ROS enabled quadrotor sim.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-01-11**:
That sounds promising. The work in progress of hector_quadrotor_urdf is now available and described here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_quadrotor_urdf

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2012-01-08**:
I developed a plugin for an Autonomous Underwater Vehicle using the first method.  It worked quite well.  I avoided running the simulation externally due to concerns about lag.